# How to respond to conflicting environment names in published packages which I inadvertently inflicted on an unsuspecting public?

Tags: best-practices, package-writing

What is the best thing to do if you've inadvertently published a package which conflicts with another, where the conflict involves competing definitions of an environment?

In this case, both **prooftrees** and **bussproofs** define a `prooftree` environment. Hence, the packages cannot be loaded in the same document without modification.

The [suggested solution at LaTeX for Logicians](http://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/trees/) is to rename `prooftrees.sty` as `tableaux.sty` and then find-and-replace all occurrences of `prooftrees` by `tableaux` and all occurrences of `prooftress` by `tableau`. The `tableau` environment can then be used for **prooftrees** trees and `prooftree` for **bussproofs** trees.

However, I'm not convinced this is good advice. First, `tableaux.sty` will not get updated when `prooftrees.sty` does, so it makes maintenance tricky. Second, it will no doubt generate questions from users who will eventually forget that their `tableaux.sty` is really a (possibly outdated) copy of `prooftrees.sty`.

The user who reported the conflict suggested I rename **prooftrees** as **tableaux** and `prooftree` as `tableau`. But the existence of the **tableaux** package ruled out this name in the first place.

However, it does turn out that **tableaux** actually includes `tableau.sty` and ***not*** `tableaux.sty`, as I'd been assuming.

One way to workaround the issue at the document level is to add something like

```
\usepackage{prooftrees}
\let\othername\prooftree
\undef\prooftree
\undef\endprooftree
\usepackage{bussproofs}
```

to the preamble of the document. `othername` can then be used for **prooftrees** trees and `prooftree` for **bussproofs** trees.

One thing I could do, therefore, would be to include a `tableaux.sty` in **prooftrees** which loads `prooftrees.sty` and then does

```
\usepackage{prooftrees}
\let\tableau\prooftree
\undef\prooftree
\undef\endprooftree
```

so that users who say

```
\usepackage{tableaux}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
```

can use `tableau` for **prooftrees** trees and `prooftree` for **bussproofs** trees.

This has obvious disadvantages: `tableaux.sty` will be provided by **prooftrees** rather than **tableaux**, while `tableau.sty` is provided by **tableaux**. Moreover, the `tableau` environment will also be provided by **prooftrees** rather than **tableaux**. However, I don't think this would produce a conflict with **tableaux** because `tableau.sty` provides neither `tableau` nor `tableaux`, as far as I can tell, and neither does `minimum.sty`, the other package file included in **tableaux**.

But the approach would also require users to load the packages in the correct order, as it won't work if people write

```
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\usepackage{tableaux}
```

Or I could make `tableaux.sty` the main file and have `prooftrees.sty` load `tableaux.sty` and then

```
\let\prooftree\tableau
\undef\tableau
\undef\endtableau
```

Or I could test at the end of the preamble whether `prooftree` is defined and make it an alias for `tableau`, if not.

But all of these options are messy and complicated. Moreover, I'm not sure if the above workaround is really safe or not.

In chat, barbara suggested just adding a workaround into the documentation. However, I wonder how many people will actually read that rather than turning to the net and creating a personalised `tableaux.sty`. On the other hand, maybe I am overstating the disadvantages of people doing this and this isn't such a bad workaround after all.

Of course, it would all be a lot easier if **bussproofs** defined `bussproof` rather than `prooftree` .... :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd not try to be too fancy with detecting package order etc as it makes the behaviour hard to document.

I'd just have two package options `prooftree` and  `tableau` and if either option is used then call the environment that.

if neither option is used then it's up to you what the default would be.
You could default to `tableau` so avoiding a clash but make existing users add `[prooftrees]` if they do not want to change documents or  make it default to `[prooftrees]` unless that environment is already defined in which case it defaults to `[tableau]` that would make the common case of just loading one package work as before, and the case of loading `bussproofs` then `prooftrees` avoid a clash.

that leaves loading `bussproofs` after `prooftrees` open to error but you could only avoid that by delaying everything to begin document so probably I wouldn't, just document that the user might need the `tableau` option or change the package order.

Comment: Thanks. I'm inclined to think this is the best option. However, egreg's suggestion would be more flexible. It just seems potentially more problematic/chaotic, I guess. Do you have a reason not to let users pick a name?

Comment: @cfr never give users choice:-) Not really any reason, Although it makes it harder perhaps to document or give examples as you will never know what the element is called or when users post disconnected fragments `\begin{wibble}..\end{wibble}` it will be harder to guess what package it came from. You see similar things with math alphabet packages which give a fixed choice of name of script font \euscr or \mathscr or \mathcal etc

Comment: I can't really tell if you're serious or not ;). And isn't your solution more like the fixed-choice maths packages than egreg's? Or is that your point?

Comment: @cfr yes sorry that is what I meant.

Comment: Actually, egreg's solution is the same. However, I *think* your answer was posted first.

Comment: "I'd just have two package options prooftree and tableau and if either option is used then call the environment that." Can anyone provide code on that? It seems to be obvious for someone proficient in LaTeX but I just started using it.

Answer (score 13):

In the options section, add

```
\def\prooftree@name{prooftree}
\DeclareOption{altprooftree}{\def\prooftree@name{altprooftree}}
```

Then in the final part do

```
\NewEnviron{\prooftree@name}[1]{%
  [...]
}
```

Thus a user wanting to use `bussproofs` can load

```
\usepackage[altprooftree]{prooftrees}
```

and use `altprooftree` in the document.